# java code,i want to make sure im doing it correctly?

Tags: java, validation

so i have to design and implement the class Clock to implement the time of the day in a program....
i have all of it done i just need help with these two last parts(not sure if its correct how i did it)
1.increase hour when minute is greater than or equal to 60.
increase minute when seconds is greater than or equal to 60.
2. inputTime inputs a hour,minutes and seconds for a clock object.Validate the input(hours 0-23.minutes 0-59,and seconds 0-59)

this is what i have
1.

```
while (Minutes >= 60) {
   Minutes = Minutes - 60;
   Hours = Hours + 1;
}

while (Seconds >= 60) {
    Seconds = Seconds - 60;
    Minutes = Minutes + 1;
}
```

2.

```
public void inputTime() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter Hours = ");
    Hours = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Minutes = ");
    Minutes = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Seconds = ");
    Seconds = input.nextInt();

    //validates the input
    if (0 <= Hours && Hours < 24)
        Hours = Hours;
    else
        System.out.println("invalid");

    if (0 <= Minutes && Minutes < 60) 
        Minutes = Minutes;
    else
        System.out.println("invalid");

    if (0 <= Seconds && Seconds < 60)
        Seconds = Seconds;
    else
        System.out.println("invalid");
}
```

Comment: Your code would be much easier to read if you respected Java Coding Conventions - in particular, variables start with a small cap (unless they are constants, all large caps).

Comment: Not to mention post well formatted code. This code is all left-justified and near impossible to read and easily understand.

Comment: In your 1st example `while
(Minutes>60 | Minutes==60);` replace the `;` with a `{` and insert a `}` at the appropiate position. Your loop will not be run as a loop if you have it like you do now.

Comment: also statements like this `Hours=Hours;` will have no effect at all.

Answer (score 2):

You code contains tons of mistakes and written without usage of any reasonable coding conventions.

1. We start variables and methods from small letter. (`Minutes`, `Seconds` etc)
2. `while(Minutes>60 | Minutes==60);` does not thing because its body is empty.
3. `Minutes>60 | Minutes==60` is syntactically wrong: you should use `||` for "or"
4. Although java allows writing `if-else` structure without `{}` it is strongly recommended for code readability
5. Java compiler ignores spaces and and tabs. However you should use indentation inside `if-else` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Few Inputs.

1. Use `||` in place of `|` in remove the `;` in the end, add curly brace to wrap next two statements.

   ```
   while(Minutes>60 || Minutes==60){
    Minutes=Minutes-60;
    Hours=Hours+1;
   }
   while(Seconds>60 || Seconds==60){
     Seconds=Seconds-60;
     Minutes=Minutes+1;
   }
   ```
2. Have the second processing before minute processing as your `seconds` processing changes the `minutes` which should be taken care when processing `minutes`.

   ```
   while(Seconds>60 || Seconds==60){
     Seconds=Seconds-60;
     Minutes=Minutes+1;
   }
   while(Minutes>60 || Minutes==60){
    Minutes=Minutes-60;
    Hours=Hours+1;
   }
   ```
3. Use the right naming convention i.e. Class Name to start with Upper Case while method and variables start with lower case.
4. Close the `Scanner` in the end, once you are done reading the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a loop you can compute how many times it would go around.

```
minutes += seconds / 60;
seconds %= 60;
hours += minutes / 60;
minutes %= 60;
```

Note: you should compute the adjustment on the `seconds` first as it could alter the number of hours.